# How to merge calls using the Android API?

Tags: android

I am building an Android app for quick conference calls. The user should be able to conference a list of three numbers by clicking on one button. So programmatically I want to call each number and once the other person picks up I want to merge the calls.

In the program I call the first person using Intent.CALL_ACTION, wait till the call is connected then put the user on hold. Then do the same for the second number. Now when the second call is connected I want to merge it with the first call.

Are there any Android APIs which can merge calls?

Comment: > Are there any android apis which can do the call merge? No[.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ly3Ew3wQ4PA)

Comment: The idea seems good to me. Did you have look at [this](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.ammeon.gcs&feature=search_result) before? How is it different from what you need?